# Allow Fill-in For Lookup Columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

Is it possible to enable Allow Fill-in option for Lookup type columns, like Choice type columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such functionality out of the box.

Overver, there is a codeplex solution that implements that. [SharePoint 2010 Autocomplete Lookup Field](http://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/) (made by the user Nadeem Yousuf) - it implements a custom field type that adds autocomplete functionality to the lookup. You can have a look at it.

Comment: Glad to see people taking notice of one of my custom solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Managed Metadata columns if the term set is defined as Open, and you set it on the column.